# Seq.sumBy vs Seq.groupBy

Tags: f#, pipeline

I am trying to convert some pieces of C# code to F# in order to practice.
While doing so, I stumbled on a position calculation. The logic is to group by counterparty and security and sum algebraically the nominal in order to calculate the position.

```
let position instance =
        portfolio
        |> Seq.filter (isActive instance)
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun trade -> trade.Counterparty, trade.Bond)
        |> Seq.map (fun ((cp, bond), trades) -> cp, bond.Isin, trades |> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> t.Nominal))
```

The pipeline above produces the expected outcome but it feels like that it could be simplified a bit.
That's what I would have done in C#, filter, group and then project it by either using an anonymous type or creating a DTO and using that.

| Counterparty | Bond | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | FR100 | 100 |
| A | DE100 | -100 |
| B | FR100 | 200 |
| C | DE100 | 100 |

Setting up the example:

```
type Bond = {Isin : string; Maturity : DateTime; Price : float}
type Trade = {Bond: Bond; Nominal : float; Counterparty : string}
let french = {Isin = "FR100"; Maturity = DateTime(2021,12,31); Price = 122.2}
let deutch = {Isin = "DE100"; Maturity = DateTime(2021,12,31); Price = 100.2}
let expired = {Isin = "XX100"; Maturity = DateTime(2020,12,31); Price = 111.2}
let one = {Bond= expired; Nominal = 199.0; Counterparty = "A"}
let two = {Bond= expired; Nominal = 200.0; Counterparty = "B"}
let three = {Bond= french; Nominal = 100.0; Counterparty = "A"}
let four = {Bond= french; Nominal = 200.0; Counterparty = "B"}
let five = {Bond= deutch; Nominal = 100.0; Counterparty = "A"}
let six = {Bond= deutch; Nominal = -200.0; Counterparty = "A"}
let seven = {Bond= deutch; Nominal = 100.0; Counterparty = "C"}
let portfolio = [|one;two;three;four;five;six;seven|]

let instrumentHasMatured instance bond = bond.Maturity < instance
let isActive instance trade = not (instrumentHasMatured instance trade.Bond)
```

Comment: It looks good to me. I don't see a way to simplify beyond filter, group, project. Each of those seems fundamental. FWIW, LINQ in C# is very similar to the `Seq` module in F# because both are pure functional approaches, so it's often a straight 1:1 translation between them. F# often requires fewer keystrokes, though.

Comment: Welcome to the F# community! I see no way to significantly simplify this. If `portfolio` is really an array, then consider using the `Array` module instead of the `Seq` module.

Comment: If your code produces expected results then the question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ScottHutchinson usage of `seq` yields overall better performance than using of `array` or `list` in long transformations because we don't materialize entire collection after each operation.

Comment: @JL0PD I would love to see an article explaining that and when one should use the `Array` module vs the `Seq` module.